# Find the value of $\frac{t^{4012}+37}{2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, real-numbers, radicals

"Want a hint for this question as I am not getting it how to start."
$$\sqrt[4012]{55+12\sqrt {21}}×\sqrt[2006]{3\sqrt 3 - 2\sqrt 7} = t$$

Then find the value of, 
                                        $$\frac{t^{4012}+37}{2}$$

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  Please edit it.  *root* makes no sense; $t^4 012$ makes no sense.  Etc.

Comment: By ${\rm root}(4012)(...)$, do you mean $\sqrt[4012]{...} = (...)^{1/4012}$? If that is the case, use the construct `\sqrt[4012]{...}` and/or `(...)^{1/4012}` to format them.

Comment: Hint: Calculate $(3\sqrt3-2\sqrt7)^2$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t^{4012}=(55+12\sqrt{21})(3\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{7})^2=(55+12\sqrt{21})(27+28-12\sqrt{21})=(55+12\sqrt{21})(55-12\sqrt{21})=3025-144 \cdot 21=3025-3024=1$

Therefore $\frac{t^{4012}+37}{2}=\frac{1+37}{2}=\frac{38}{2}=19$

Answer (score 0):

You know I assume that, for any $a$ and $n$, $\sqrt[n]{a}^n=\sqrt[n]{a^n}=a$. So in particular $\sqrt[4012]{a}^{4012}=a$. Moreover $4012=2006*2$, so $\sqrt[2006]{a}^{4012}=(\sqrt[2006]{a}^{2006})^2= a^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$$3\sqrt3-2\sqrt7<0,$$ which says that a real value of $t$ does not exist and the needed value does not exist.